# OpenGL load & render png to screen

Tags: java, c++, opengl, graphics, jogl

I'm trying to load a crosshair png I have to a game I'm developing with OpenGL, more precisely JOGL.

The crosshair should be loaded to the center of the screen.

However even after scanning the internet for few hours - haven't found a method to simply render pngs to screen with JOGL, something that I belive is pretty easy.

All the answers I found was regarding textures, and that's not what I'm looking for since I'm not planning to make an object for this - just to show it on screen when needed.

### Edit:

After eldo's advice, tried to do the following in the display method:

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    try {
        Texture text = TextureIO.newTexture(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/misc/crosshair.png"),true, "png");
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_REPEAT );
        gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_REPEAT );
        text.bind(gl);
    } catch (GLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    float sizeX = 20, sizeY = 20, sizeZ = 20;
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);

    // create crosshair square
    gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, sizeY, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(sizeX, sizeY, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
    gl.glVertex3d(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
    gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, sizeY, sizeZ);


    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

However the result I get is (the other stuff is just walls):
[image]

Here's the crosshair png: 
[image: crosshair]

Comment: "*something that I belive is pretty easy*" Well, it isn't. That's not how OpenGL works. If you want to render an image, you have to make a texture for it. At least, in modern OpenGL.

Comment: _"I'm not planning to make an object for this"_ OpenGL has no concept of objects. It draws points, lines, and triangles onto the screen. It sounds like you want a higher-level framework or engine rather than OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see. So you say I must place it in the world and then apply texture to it?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo You're right, I wasn't precise. I have made Java objects for every object in my game, which holds the data (in this case, a path to it's resource .obj file along with extra data such as position in world, etc). That's why I said object.

Comment: Take a look at the Hello Texture [here](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just draw an image that easily in middle of your screen, OpenGL wont 'forget' its actual state and render your image as you wish. But in a few steps you can make it able to draw it after you finished rendering all your 3D stuffs.

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION); //reset the projection matrix
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);//change to orthographic projection
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);// reset the modelview matrix
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);//disable depth test
//draw 2D stuff here
```

After this you can draw a quad in the middle of your screen with a crosshair texture on it.

Comment: Except for disabling depth test, this is all old, deprecated OpenGL.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two It is, still its a working solution and can be replaced with new stuff. Its not a working solution anyway, just an example or concept. Also he is not providing any code so cannot answer what he needs exaclty.

Comment: I added some code which didn't work for some reason... can you take a look?

Comment: @Jjang The 'other stuff' looks as it should like? It looks like you are in a corner.

Comment: @Jjang I dont see all your code and im not even an expert but here is a working example of textures: https://github.com/xranby/modern-jogl-examples/commit/a9fa95dd683790272b052f4a895a0ddfaf0f8a73

Comment: @Jjang and the two glTexParameteri lines should be called after you bind a texture.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't managed to set the texture properly yet, opening another question.